# Datanucleus Rest API Sample

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, datanucleus

About a month ago I tried to implement Datanucleus Rest API on top of my Appengine web application, however I have encountered a lot of problems especially on which dependencies to include specifically. I have so much mismatch with dependencies I put in the `POM`.

- So my question is, is there any sample web app which uses Datanucleus
  Rest API such that all the correct dependencies are there in the POM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the maven plugin I am using:
[maven-gae-plugin](https://github.com/maven-gae-plugin/maven-gae-plugin)

There are some interesting templates there to start there! If you need help I am working on that since last year!